# In Ansible, how can I use different template substitutions based on a variable value?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-template

I have a template of a system.d service script that I get filled using Ansible playbook.

The template includes experssion

```
[Service]
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Denvironmentname={{environment_name | default('NOT_SET') }}"
```

where **environment_name** above is a variable present in Ansible while running the playbook. Playbook has this instruction:

```
- name: Copy systemd service script
  template: src=systemd.service dest="{{systemd_dir}}/{{systemd_service_name}}.service"
```

I want to add memory-related parameters to the JAVA_OPTS such as:

**if** environment_name=DEV, **then** add to JAVA_OPTS '-Xmx=2000Mb -Xms=1000Mb', **if** environment_name=PROD, **then** add '-Xmx=20000Mb -Xms=10000Mb'*, etc (I have several environments).

How I can encode such substitutions in template or in calling script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `if` Jinja template directive.  Maybe something like:

```
{% if environment_name == 'DEV' %}
{% set extra_java_opts = "-Xmx=2000Mb -Xms=1000Mb" %}
{% elif environment_name == 'PROD' %}
{% set extra_java_opts = "-Xmx=20000Mb -Xms=10000Mb" %}
{% endif %}
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Denvironmentname={{environment_name | default('NOT_SET') }} {{ extra_java_opts }}"
```

This isn't the only way of tackling this problem (for example, you could put an `if` block inline in the `Environment=` statement, but I think that gets messy).

Read through the [control structures](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list-of-control-structures) section of the Jinja documentation for more information about `if`/`then`, and read about [assignments](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments) for information about the `set` directive.

Having said that, I would probably put this logic in my ansible playbook, rather than embedding it in the template:

```
- set_fact:
    extra_java_opts: "-Xmx=2000Mb -Xms=1000Mb"
  when: environment == 'DEV'

- set_fact:
    extra_java_opts: "-Xmx=20000Mb -Xms=10000Mb"
  when: environment == 'PROD'
```

This makes the templates much simpler, and keeps all your logic in one place rather than splitting it between the playbooks and the templates.